# Unexpected error occurred when tried to create an Android project with phonegap-2.8.1 on mac os x

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, cordova

I get the error when tried to create an android project with phonegap latest version on mac mini. I followed the getting stared docs provided by cordova. I also edited my bash profile and included android sdk tools and platform-tools path.

But when execute the ./create command I got that error

```
    An unexpected error occurred: "$ANDROID_BIN" create project --target $TARGET --path "$PROJECT_PATH" --package $PACKAGE --activity $ACTIVITY >&/dev/null exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

I don't figured out the reason of this error. please help me...

I have read some similar post in stackoverflow but their solutions didn't help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the create file (phonegap-2.7.0/lib/android/bin/create) with textEdit, there is a line that lists

`ANDROID_BIN=”${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}”`.

The “which android” is the cause of the issue

If you replace this line with the full path to your android tools (SDK), it should resolve the issue. It looked like this:

```
ANDROID_BIN=/Users/cswjs/Documents/Dev/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/android
```

OR try modify ~/.bash_profile using `open ~/.bash_profile` to full PATH

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/cswjs/Documents/Dev/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/cswjs/Documents/Dev/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

And use `cordova create foo com.example.foo foo` to create new project named foo. Make sure project name should be same.

Hope this could help someone!

Comment: Thanks wesson for you wonderful description about the reason of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

oI have get the reason of this error.
I just need to restart my pc. After restarting my pc the ./create command create a new phonegap project for android with out any error. Not sure about that but i got my problem solved.

Thanks